# xgboost - How do I treat document ID in pairwise ranking

Tags: xgboost, ranking

I am trying to use xgboost in R for pairwise ranking for an implicit dataset.

For simplicity, let's assume that I am dealing with a search problem, where I want to rank documents relative to a given query. Each query has an ID and the documents that were clicked also have an ID. My dataset only consists of the positive feedback and looks like this:

```
queryID    documentID    features    target
   1            1            ...        1
   1            3            ...        1
   1            13           ...        1                    
   2            3            ...        1
   2            4            ...        1 
   3            990          ...        1
```

I have read, that for grouping my queries together, I have to use setinfo(group, *list*). But what do I do with my documentID, do I implement it as just another feature in my feature list?